# Chart label design chart.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, web, charts

I can't seem to find a way to display my chart like this with chart.js: [image]

I want the legends to be connected to their respective sections (with a line), as shown in the picture. Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried something like this? 
http://canvasjs.com/html5-javascript-doughnut-chart/

Comment: I did find that one, but it's not open source. Free trial for 30 days only.

Comment: How about this? D3.js is free. http://jsfiddle.net/8QvvF/

Comment: Thx! I was able to make it work with d3.js. However, it would be nice if I could do it with chart.js. Maybe someone else knows how to.